# Airflow celery with redis - timeout after 6h

Tags: redis, airflow

I'm having some troubles using `airflow 1.9.0` with `CeleryExecutor` using `redis` as broker.

I need to run a job that takes more than 6 hours to complete and I'm losing my celery workers.
Looking into airflow code in GitHub, There is a hard-coded configuration:

https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/d760d63e1a141a43a4a43daee9abd54cf11c894b/airflow/config_templates/default_celery.py#L31

How could I bypass this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is configurable in airflow.cfg under the section `celery_broker_transport_options`.

See the commit adding this possibility https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/commit/be79f87f36b6b99649e0a1f6ab92b41640b3beaa

Comment: The problem is that this commit is only available on branch `1.10.0-rc1` =(
I ended replacing redis by rabbitmq